# How did Nomak learn about the supposedly secret location where Blade was being held?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-ii

In the following dialogue in [*Blade II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_II), Kounen was talking about Nomak to the captured Blade:

> **KOUNEN:** But fortunately for us, he doesn't know this location.
>
> **BLADE:** Now... he does.

The above dialogue was followed by a scene of Nomak attacking the vampires' security forces in the supposedly secret location where Blade was being held.

**How did Nomak learn about the supposedly secret location where Blade was being held?** Was Blade at some point able to communicate or let Nomak know about the location?

Comment: @Community What to do with the `blade-ii` tag? While the official title is indeed *Blade II*, that tag looks awful compared to `blade-2`, given that this *"II"* is just a sequel number really.

Comment: @ChristianRau That probably should be asked at [meta].

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't want to start yet another meta discussion about a single damn tag. But maybe one could make a larger more general discussion out of it.

Comment: @ChristianRau I just made [a meta post](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1073/1006) about it.

Comment: Maybe Whistler told him in the tunnels....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the sequence in the tunnels, Blade is buying time for the remainder of the Bloodpack to get clear, as they will be affected by the UV bomb and Blade is unharmed by sunlight.

[image: screencap of the described scene]

The UV bomb's remote detonation fails, meaning Blade has to get to the package and trigger it manually. In order to draw the Reapers towards him, Blade *smashes a vial of Reaper Pheromones on his chest*, making him a distinctive, traceable target for Reapers.

None of The Bloodpack are present at this point, and as such they would not know that Blade had
done this, which would explain their surprise when Nomak is able to trace him so easily.

Answer (score 1):

Blade led (or should I say *bled*) him right to the location.

[David Goyer's script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Blade_II_David_goyer.html) makes it clear in the dialogue that immediately followed your **quoted** quote:

```
                            STEVENS
                  You may be right.  Fortunately for us,
                  he has no idea where this facility is
                  located.

        Blade smiles, laughing tiredly.

                            BLADE
                  He does now.
                      (off their concerned looks)
                  He's been watching me since the tunnels.
                  Following me.  I led him right to you.

        Blade lifts up his hand, unfurling his previously closed
        fist.  There is a deep gash in his palms.

                            BLADE (CONT'D)
                  Just like a trail of bread crumbs.

        Damaskinos stares at Blade's hand, then looks to the floor.
        A line of blood droplets lead back to the doors through which
        he entered.
```

Comment: "*David Goyer's script makes it clear in the dialogue that immediately followed your **quoted** quote*" Are you sure that script is genuine? The dialogue I quoted was directly from the film, not from a version of a script not used in the film. I rewatched the film and the ff: lines by Blade that you quoted from that script were not in there: (1) "*He's been watching me since the tunnels.*", (2) "*Following me.  I led him right to you.*" (3) "*Just like a trail of bread crumbs.*"

Comment: ... These scenes were also not in the movie: (1) "*Blade lifts up his hand, unfurling his previously closed fist.  There is a deep gash in his palms.*" (2) "*Damaskinos stares at Blade's hand, then looks to the floor. A line of blood droplets lead back to the doors through which he entered.*" Could you match the info you've quoted in that script with the events or dialogue which appeared in the film?

Comment: The question asked for a plot explanation which often results in a "best fit" answer as opposed to pure speculation. Agreed that the actual movie never used it, but wanted to fill in the blanks as to the "why" using what I assumed was the original script by Goyer.

Comment: Is Blade not brought to the Vampire Hideout by Helicopter? I'm sure there is a sequence showing him being dragged inside through a rooftop entryway...that would make the trail a breadcrumbs a little ludicrous..