# How do they decide Blu-ray/DVD release date?

Tags: film-industry, distribution

I think my question is different from [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15927/how-do-studios-decide-which-movie-classic-to-release-on-blu-ray).

Some movies' productions release Blu-ray/DVD so early after theatrical release, others will take time. How do they decide for the Blu-ray/DVD release date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regional thing.   In the UK it's normally 17 weeks by agreement with cinemas.  Famously in 2010 they upset the cinemas by trying a 14 week window to avoid a clash with the World Cup:

From Wikipedia

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_distribution

> In early 2010, Disney announced it would be putting out the DVD and Blu-ray versions of Tim Burton's Alice in Wonderland 14 weeks after the movie's release date (instead of the usual 17) in order to avoid competition from the 2010 World Cup.[10] In response to such statements, theater owners made threats not to show the movie on their screens,[21] but later reconsidered their position before the movie was released.[19]